# Back-fill NAs in a column only if the subsequent value matches a specific value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have some longitudinal patient data that includes a column describing whether the patient currently is or has ever been a smoker. I want to back-fill missing values *only* if the patient is later registered as never having been a smoker. I cannot simply use [tiydr::fill](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html), as it doesn't allow discriminating on the value.

Given the example below, I want the ´NA´s for `id==1` to be replaced by `never_smoker`, while `id==2` should remain unchanged, as we cannot accurately infer when the patient started smoking.

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~visit, ~smoking,
  1, 1, NA,
  1, 2, NA,
  1, 3, "never_smoker",
  2, 1, NA,
  2, 2, NA,
  2, 3, "current_smoker"
)
```

Should result in

```r
expected_result <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~visit, ~smoking,
  1, 1, "never_smoker",
  1, 2, "never_smoker",
  1, 3, "never_smoker",
  2, 1, NA,
  2, 2, NA,
  2, 3, "current_smoker"
)
```

I came up with this solution, which seems to work, but requires reversing the column twice. I expect there must be a better way to do this?

```r
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(smoking = rev(accumulate(rev(smoking), ~ ifelse(is.na(.y) & .x == "never_smoker", "never_smoker", .y))))
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer - but I realized it failed if there’s more than one non-missing instance of `"never_smoker"` for a given `id`. I’ve edited it to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the highest `visit` with a value of `"never_smoker"`, then fill in visits less than this.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(smoking = if_else(
    visit < suppressWarnings(max(visit[!is.na(smoking) & smoking == "never_smoker"])), 
    "never_smoker", 
    smoking
  ))
```

`suppressWarnings()` is included because `max()` will warn about returning `-Inf` if there’s no value of `"never_smoker"`, but in this case that’s the behavior we want.

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id visit smoking       
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
1     1     1 never_smoker  
2     1     2 never_smoker  
3     1     3 never_smoker  
4     2     1 <NA>          
5     2     2 <NA>          
6     2     3 current_smoker
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do the logical test `!(smoking != 'never_smoker' | is.na(smoking))` then you will get `TRUE` if the entry is "never smoker" and `FALSE` otherwise. If you reverse this vector and do a cumulative sum, and reverse *that* result to put it back in the original order, then any values occurring on or before "never smoking" will be greater than 0. This allows a simple `ifelse` to label the `smoking` column as "never smoker" if the entry is positive, and leave it as-is otherwise.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(smoking = ifelse(rev(cumsum(
    rev(!(smoking != 'never_smoker' | is.na(smoking))))) > 0, 
    'never smoker', smoking), .by = 'id')
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      id visit smoking       
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1     1     1 never smoker  
#> 2     1     2 never smoker  
#> 3     1     3 never smoker  
#> 4     2     1 NA            
#> 5     2     2 NA            
#> 6     2     3 current_smoker
```